# not a single-group group function sum

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

So this is what I have

`SELECT idproduct, quantity FROM bb_basketitem ORDER BY idproduct;`

```
IDPRODUCT              QUANTITY               
---------------------- ---------------------- 
2                      1                      
4                      1                      
4                      1                      
6                      1                      
6                      1                      
6                      2                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
7                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      2                      
8                      1                      
8                      1                      
8                      2                      
9                      2                      
9                      2                      
9                      1                      
9                      1                      
10                     1                      
10                     2
```

> 28 rows selected

I want to display the total quantity for each product by `idproduct`, I feel like it should work like the following.

`SELECT idproduct, sum(quantity) FROM bb_basketitem ORDER BY idproduct;`

But when I execute the query I get the following error.

> Error starting at line 1 in command: select idproduct,  sum(quantity)
>   from bb_basketitem order by   idproduct Error at Command Line:1
>   Column:7 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group
>   function
>   00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: For future reference, when you get an Oracle error message a simple search on the ORA error number is quite likely to turn up the correct answer. For instance [here are the search results for ORA-00937](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ora-00937)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `group by` clause. The query should be like:

```
select idproduct, sum(quantity) 
from bb_basketitem 
group by idproduct
order by idproduct;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you include an aggregate function in the select list of your SQL statement, you need to list all non-aggregated columns with a group by clause like below ( assuming you have three columns `idproduct`, `col2`, `col3` in the select list ):

```
select idproduct, col2, col3, sum(quantity), avg(col3), min(idproduct)
  from bb_basketitem
 group by idproduct, col2, col3;
```